# Issue with loading and retraining the model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to retrain a model, when I try to load the model, I get this error. Can anyone help, how to fix this?

```
model.load_weights(config.training.weights_path, by_name=True) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2232, in load_weights
    f, self.layers, skip_mismatch=skip_mismatch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 761, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    layer, weight_values, original_keras_version, original_backend)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 405, in preprocess_weights_for_loading
    weights[0] = np.transpose(weights[0], (3, 2, 0, 1))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in transpose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 653, in transpose
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 58, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

I saw some people here, saying to change the file extension of the model from .h5 to .hdf5 but I didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you re-read the rules, how to post questions with MCVE-based problem formulation. C-ompleteness, V-erifiability ( of solution ) lack a reproducible example of code, that throws the above copy/pasted ( part ) of an unhandled exception's traceback. Once completed a truly MCVE-based problem, Community members here are very good at providing help and directions how to fix it. Feel free to improve your post in this direction & enjoy your new membership

Comment: The is issue mainly with loading the pre-trained model. For some reason it's not being loaded correctly.